# How to stream a capture video using Picamera2

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, picamera

I trying to use a example of the Picamera2 the **capture_stream_udp.py** to create a client, but a dont know how to create a server script to capture a udp stream via socket.

Can you guys help?

```html
#!/usr/bin/python3

import socket
import time

from picamera2 import Picamera2
from picamera2.encoders import H264Encoder
from picamera2.outputs import FileOutput

picam2 = Picamera2()
video_config = picam2.create_video_configuration({"size": (1280, 720)})
picam2.configure(video_config)
encoder = H264Encoder(1000000)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as sock:
    sock.connect(("REMOTEIP", 10001))
    stream = sock.makefile("wb")
    picam2.start_recording(encoder, FileOutput(stream))
    time.sleep(20)
    picam2.stop_recording()
```

Comment: Have you tried following along with a tutorial on this subject - like [this one](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/video-streaming-with-raspberry-pi-camera/)?

Comment: https://pyshine.com/Video-and-bidirectional-text-streaming/

Comment: This is good tutorial for client/server. 
 https://jmlb.github.io/robotics/2017/11/22/picamera_streaming_video/

Answer (score 1):

I found the secret to be `FfmpegOutput`.  This code below will stream RTP wrapped H.264 to a UDP destination using Picamera2  (aka python interface to libcamera libraries).

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from time import sleep
from picamera2 import Picamera2
from picamera2.encoders import H264Encoder
from picamera2.outputs import FfmpegOutput

picam2 = Picamera2()
picam2.configure(picam2.create_video_configuration(main={"size": (1280, 720),
                                                         "format": "YUV420"}))
picam2.start_recording(H264Encoder(), output=FfmpegOutput("-f rtp udp://192.168.168.110:9000"))
count = 0
while True:
    print(f'hello [{count}]')
    count += 1
    sleep(2)
```

You can receive the UDP streaming video with this gstreamer pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=9000 caps='application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264' ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```